# Replace element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JS. I have Datatable JS.
I have this code:

```
$('.data-table').on('click', 'td', function () {
 var row = table.row(this).data();
 console.log(row.action);
});
```

This code return:

```
<I id="12" class="fas fa-plus addItem"></I>
```

or

```
<i id="11" class="fas fa-minus removeItem"></i>
```

I want replace after click:
1. When result is

> ```
> <I id="11" class="fas fa-plus addItem"></I>
> ```

- i want replace by

> ```
> <I id="11" class="fas fa-minus removeItem"></I>
> ```

2. When result is

> ```
> <I id="30" class="fas fa-plus removeItem"></I>
> ```

- i want replace by

> ```
> <I id="30" class="fas fa-minus addItem"></I>
> ```

How can I make it?

Comment: tried `toggleClass`? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass_2

Comment: cab you give me sample code?

Comment: Please clarify your question slightly, it's a bit unclear. Use format:
`Input`
`Current Output`
`Expected Output`
`Trigger Element` on whose click you want it triggered.

Comment: look at my code. id is variable, depending on what the user clicks

Comment: I also don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Please include a working example.

Comment: Use `<button>` not `<i>`, or do `<i  role="button">` for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed Id:

```
$('#30').removeClass('fa-plus removeItem').addClass('fa-minus addItem')
```

else if you can add a class to that `<i class='myclickableclass fas ...'>`
then you could use `$('.myclickableclass')` instead of the `$('#30')`

Or use your datatable markup like:

`$('.datatable td i')` instead.

Comment: is check removeItem or addItem and make somethink like this: $.get("{{ route('related.product.add') }}" + '/......./' + mainProduct + '/' + row.id, function (data, status) {
                    console.log('ok');
                });

Comment: Ya that can work too, provided he just wants to toggle.. not very clear by his question!

Comment: Yes, I want change my + / - and send $get .... with selected parameter